# How to retrieve some information without using file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm searching a way to retrieve data (csv format) from something which is not a file, let me explain.

In the company i'm in actually they quit Fileserver to Google Drive - So i'm actually trying to read information from a google spreadsheet but it didn't work nicely so far.

Any idea how to do this ? Any other idea on a way to centralise datas (CSV format) which is neither fileserver or using GDrive ?

The data source should be easily modified (no database..)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to export a google spreadsheet to CSV automatically?

Comment: This looks like it might work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107387/export-all-sheets-in-a-google-spreadsheet-as-csv

Comment: spreadsheet could be a solution, i'm asking if there could be other solution i didn't think about

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your'e after but to me "Any other idea on a way to centralise datas (CSV format) which is neither fileserver or using GDrive" - the next step is to store it in tables in a database. It really depends on your constraints and requirements, which you have not mentioned.

Comment: I think you're right and since i can't manage a database I ended using GoogleSpreadsheet. Thanks for the input !